# How can I take a slice of a frame or vector by date?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data frame where the row.names correspond to date values.

```
$ cat data.csv
date    actusers    passive
2010-12-31  162 55
2011-01-01  291 167
2011-01-02  270 200
2011-01-03  341 269
2011-01-04  412 324
2011-01-05  409 309
2011-01-06  481 329
2011-01-07  511 358
2011-01-08  364 213

$ r
> data = read.csv("data.csv", row.names=1, sep='\t')
> data
           actusers passive
2010-12-31      162      55
2011-01-01      291     167
2011-01-02      270     200
2011-01-03      341     269
2011-01-04      412     324
2011-01-05      409     309
2011-01-06      481     329
2011-01-07      511     358
2011-01-08      364     213
```

How can I make slices of this data frame by specifying date ranges?

Comment: when you say "slices" are you thinking of subsetting or would you like to slice and then iterate over each slice (kinda like an SQL group by)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Dates, you can use simply the mathematical operators for this. Alternatively you can combine `seq()` and `%in%` :

```
zz <- textConnection("
dates           actusers passive
2010-12-31      162      55
2011-01-01      291     167
2011-01-02      270     200
2011-01-03      341     269
2011-01-04      412     324
2011-01-05      409     309
2011-01-06      481     329
2011-01-07      511     358
2011-01-08      364     213")

Data <- read.table(zz,header=T,as.is=T)
close(zz)

Data$dates <- as.Date(Data$dates)

id <- Data$dates < as.Date("2011-01-06")
Data[id,]

Seq <- seq.Date(as.Date("2011-01-03"),as.Date("2011-01-07"),by="day")

Data[Data$dates %in% Seq,]
```

Comment: @ʞɔıu : see ?as.Date for more info on reading different formats. I took the data as you printed it from the screen. When using read.table, are you sure you used the option `sep=","`: Data = read.table("data.csv", header=T,as.is=T,sep=","). Check `str(Data)` to make sure that you have the correct dataframe, and that dates is NOT a factor.

Answer (score 6):

If you're doing a lot with time series data you may find the xts package useful. It provides a number of syntactic tools for working with time series data. For example, if you wanted all the observations that fall in June of 2007 you can get there with this example taken almost verbatim from the [xts vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/vignettes/xts.pdf):

```
require(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
matrix_xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, dateFormat = "Date")
matrix_xts['2007-06']
```